# Do I report conference posters to researchfish?

Tags: funding, united-kingdom

For RCUK funded PhD students in their 3rd year onward they are asked to report to researchfish.

I'm in this position and can't find any information on if I need to report conference posters or not.

Does anyone know if I need to report conference posters to researchfish? If so what category does it fall under?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My experience is with RCUK grant reporting - I've helped some of our PhD students with reporting but only informally so can't speak to exactly what's expected. That said, this is the advice I'd give them...

The [general approach](http://www.rcuk.ac.uk/documents/documents/rcukresearchfishfaq-pdf/) for *grantholders* is that simply attending/speaking at a conference is considered business as usual and not something you need to report unless you a) the paper was published (in which case, it's a "publication"), or b) you were specially invited to speak ("awards and recognition").

For students, [the guidance (sec. 18)](http://www.rcuk.ac.uk/documents/documents/studentshipfaqs-pdf/) is a little less explicit - however, when they say you don't need to report conferences, they discuss it in the context of "instances where you communicated your research", which would seem to imply that they include giving a paper or a poster alongside conference attendance.

If in doubt, though, your institutional reporting contact should be able to advise - there's a [list here](http://www.rcuk.ac.uk/research/researchoutcomes/rolist/). And congratulations for thinking about this now - most people won't give it any thought until early March!

Comment: Thanks, I will ask my reporting contact and report back.